# Asp core web-api session is empty after return ok()

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, session

In my project in the auth controller, I create OTP code and return to the user
and if a user sends another request for code its check for the session to see if the user gets it before or not
but after the new request I check `HttpContext.Session.Keys` and it's empty

it's only working on postman
not any browser

My startup class

```
services.AddMvcCore(config =>
{
    config.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
    config.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;
    config.Filters.Add(typeof(RequireHttpsAttribute));
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
})
 .AddApiExplorer()
 .AddFormatterMappings()
 .AddDataAnnotations()
 .AddCors(opt =>
    opt.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
    builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials())
 ).AddNewtonsoftJson(opt =>
    {
        opt.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling =
        Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    });
services.AddResponseCaching();
services.AddHsts(opt =>
{
    opt.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
});
```

And

```
seeder.SeedUsers();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    RequestPath = new PathString("/wwwroot")
});
app.UseSession();
```

In another project it's working perfectly I don't know whats wrong

Comment: Are u using chrome? Please inspect the response for the login request, it should contain the cookies, if they're marked with a yellow warning symbol, means that chrome is refusing them, probably because of "SameSite" attribute

Comment: it's working in postman, what should I do? it's not working in any browser @pablo-recalde

Comment: it has this part in response header set-cookie: .AspNetCore.Session=CfDJ8ERmiwQ1NvZDnWm0tchsxytaeVBVvqPdD%2BnWzaBrzqO2%2FRsqmzzAJeeCzTrbykQUc7A4Li0oV3W9ZqgHbtdyFQE8jbrTDGWlQx81CCEmbw1O0Dg3RRgoAgZlpj0YFbSRe%2FQLmcQ20nylsjK2VjOMTV1DSab8L3XQVgfEFRgK4dAA; path=/; samesite=lax; httponly
  @pablo-recalde

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i assume U are using angualr in clicent side

so

In production mode  client and the web api on the same site so u have no problem with the session but in development mode your angular is hosted on localhost:4200 which reset the session on each call to a service.

u can host the angular and the web api on the same host on development mode but it means I have to do ng build all the time(which will have a big overhead).

use other ways to save your code